# Asp.net MVC3 passing model within model in an action link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-parameters

I'm having problem passing my model via an object link

Here is my model

```
public class ItemImage
{
    [Required,Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Width { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Height { get; set; }

}
public class UserItem
{
    public UserItem()
    {
        Image = new ItemImage();
        Private = true;
    }

    #region
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EAN { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Publisher  { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Binding { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(ItemType))]
    public ItemType Type { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(ItemStatus))]
    public ItemStatus Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ItemImage Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Private { get; set; }
    #endregion
} // other properties
}

// the view code
       @foreach (InventoryApp.Models.UserItem item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                     @Html.ActionLink("Add To Library", "Add",item)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

// the controller

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Add(UserItem item)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

here is what the url (action link) looks like, as you can see my embedded model object doesn't pass correctly

`Add/0?Image=InventoryApp.Models.ItemImage&amp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload of `ActionLink` that you're using is expecting a route value. Depending on what your action is expecting, something like this should work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add To Library", "Add", new { Url = item.Url })
```

This is assuming that your `Add` action is expecting a string url.

On the other hand, if you're expecting to *pass* your entire model to the action, that isn't possible.

Comment: Hmm ended breaking down and passing only the import attributes i need to recreate my model object on they server side and than added it to the database.